# Impresion de Mapa con gvNix en colores

Tags: spring, gvnix, spring-roo

En gvNix existe una herramienta de impresión para el mapa que es el siguiente tag `<tool:print id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_print"/>` el mismo me funciona perfecto la cuestión es que al darle imprimir la imagen me sale en blanco y negro, me gustaria saber si hay alguna posibilidad de obtener la imagen a color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que yo sepa, gvNIX no cambia nada del color, por lo que me da la impresión que debe ser la configuración que tienes establecida en la impresora. La comprobación puede ser tan sencilla como imprimir a un archivo PDF o probar a imprimir en otro equipo.

Yo acabo de probar a imprimir en PDF con el chrome la [demo on-line](http://geo-gvnix.rhcloud.com/map) y me ha funcionado perfectamente.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Uh!!!! Justamente era la configuración de la impresora en el Chrome .. Probando con otro navegador lo verifique, disculpa y gracias nuevamente .. Habria alguna forma de contactar contigo? Quiero aclarar algunas dudas con referencia a la herramienta o las hago todas creando topic?

Comment: Usar SO es para que otros puedan encontrar respuestas a sus preguntas y que, además, mas usuarios puedan responder.